# Casting pointer type based on integer size (C99)

Tags: c, pointers, casting, c99

How do you (if possible) define a type by an integer size? For example if I wanted to make a type which was 3 bytes long how could I accomplish doing something like this? (I am aware this is incorrect)

```
typedef int24_t 3;
```

I am trying to write a generalized function which takes a character string parameter containing multiple numbers, and stores the numbers in a pointer, passed as another parameter.

However I want to make it so you can pass a numerical parameter which determines how big the variable type storing the numbers will be: i.e. if it were 1 the type could be char, if it were 4 the type could be int etc.

I am aware that it is possible to just store the number in a temporary fixed size variable, and then only copy the relevant bytes to the pointer depending on the requested size, but I want the code to be portable and I don't want to be messing around with Endianness as I've had trouble with that in the past.

Thanks

Comment: If you want the *data* to be portable, then you have to deal with endianess, there's no way around it. If the *data* will stay on only a single platform (no matter which it is), then you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: There very likely is no 24-bit integer type. Since `typedef` only creates an alias for an existing type, not a new type, there's no way around that -- if you really need it to be an integer type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a struct, it's not elegant but sounds like what you're looking for.
Note that you must define the struct alignment to 1 byte. You're also limited to 64bit.

```
typedef struct Int24 {
    int value : 24;
} Int;

typedef struct UInt24 {
    unsigned value  : 24;
} UInt24;

typedef struct Int48 {
    long long value : 48;
} Int48;
```

**With templates:**

```
template<int bytes> struct Int {
    long long value : bytes * 8;
};
typedef Int<1> Int8;
typedef Int<6> Int48;
```

**With macro:**

```
#define DECL_INT(n)          \
    typedef struct _Int##n { \
      long long value : n;   \
    } Int##n

// declaration of type
DECL_INT(48); // produces Int48

// usage
Int48 i48;
```

Comment: removed 72bit int. long day :(

Comment: I considered doing something like this, but i wanted a generalization so i didn't have to define a struct for every size of integer

Comment: Added alternative with templates

Comment: Bit fields of types other than `int`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, and (in C99 and later) `_Bool` are implementation-defined, and may not  be supported. (A plain `int` bit field is implementation-definedly equivalent to either `signed int` or `unsigned int`. This applies *only* to bit fields; in all other contexts, `int` and `signed int` are names for the same type.)

Comment: A `struct` will very likely have padding at the end -- and there's no portable way in C99 to specify alignment.

Comment: Added macro version. sizeof(Int48) will usually give you 8 bytes not 6 due to struct alignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
       struct smallerint
       {
         unsigned int integer:24; //(24=24bits=3bytes)
       };

       typedef struct smallerint int24_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well what you're trying to do, and if you want a nice generalized function, i would use linked list of bytes. Maybe you should have a look on a bigint implementation.